# WebChromeClient Integrate in Android App

Tags: android, google-chrome, android-webview, chrome-custom-tabs, webchromeclient

I'm trying to solve a problem in integrating `WebChromeClient` and try to achieve this one below (If possible).

[image: WebChrome]

Mine:

[image: WebViewClient]

Steps that I made: I create an `Activity` with `WebView` in it. And just reflect the `Url` in the toolbar as title.

**How can we somehow fuse (Fuse maybe not the right word) this to our App?** The `onCreateOptionsMenu` is from Chrome Browser as I noticed.

**EDIT: I don't know the name of it, I thought it is `webChromeClient`.**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know the exact name for this, I thought it was `webChromeClient` - but it is `Chrome Custom Tabs`. The documentation for implementations is found here:

https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/customtabs#whatarethey

Gradle: `compile 'com.android.support:customtabs:24.2.1'`

[image: ChromeTabs]

**Chrome Custom Tabs is faster** than Google Chrome Browser and WebView.

- Customization is also included

The WebView is good solution if you are hosting your own content inside your app. **If your app directs people to URLs outside your domain,** It is recommend that you use Chrome Custom Tabs for these reasons:

**NOTE:**
If there is no default browser set, it will pop up `BottomSheet` to `complete action using`. I think this should not be. We must check if `Chrome` browser is installed and launched that instead of other browser.

Answer (score 0):

For kotlin users, equivalent is `implementation 'androidx.browser:browser:1.0.0'`

Sample code can be found at https://github.com/anandwana001/mindorks-cct